# Ryzen 3 2200u laptop linux compatibility

Tags: linux, laptop, intel, amd, hardware-compatibility

Do Ryzen 3 2200u laptops work without issues with stock install of Debian 9 or Ubuntu 18.04?

I do not want to install nor patch nor compile!

I have to choose between Core i3 6006u and Ryzen 3 2200u. I know that Intel SoCs work out of the box on Linux. So they seem like a safe choice.

Any experiences? Does anyone of you own a Ryzen3 laptop and tried Linux on it?

Comment: That is, as I edited it, _experience_ _based_. NOT opinion based!

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: There are numerous issues relating to ACPI with Linux kernels older than 5.0. It's 'stable' for me with 5.1. According to https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/bkn1pq/linux_52_should_resolve_many_amd_ryzen_laptop/ 5.2 will hopefully resolve most remaining issues.

Comment: Since this is closed and the OP has deleted their account so cannot improve it, I am deleting it.

Comment: People's experiences are fundamentally opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but I have tried Debian(Kali-rolling) on a Tower with Ryzen3 2200. it worked without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Ideapad 330 with AMD Ryzen 3 2200U. I'm using Arch Linux at this time, but have tried Kali, OpenSUSE, Gentoo, Void, Fedora, lubuntu 18.10 (didn't work), Mageia, Elementary, Solus, CentOS (touchpad issues), MX (touchpad issues), and LMDE (didn't work).

In conclusion, any linux < 4.19.66 won't work probably.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you but I also experienced the same thing.

Ultimately, I found a suitable Linux version for my laptop (hp 14 cm 0008au Ryzen 3 2200u): Manjaro KDE and Pop! OS; it works without problem. I hope this can help you.